# Restore sql doesnt fire

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, asp-classic, database-restore

Im trying restore database from backup dynamically with application code

simple sql command for restore

```
con.execute("RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK='c:\old.bak' " & vbcrlf &_
        "RESTORE DATABASE newdb " & vbcrlf &_
        "FROM DISK='c:\old.bak' " & vbcrlf &_
        "WITH MOVE 'newdb' TO 'c:\newdb.mdf', " & vbcrlf &_
        "MOVE 'newdb_log' TO 'c:\newdb_log.ldf'")
```

but it doesn't fire, i mean no any errors
tried check it with sql profiler and look correctly

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK='c:\old.bak' 
RESTORE DATABASE newdb 
FROM DISK='c:\old.bak' 
WITH MOVE 'newdb' TO 'c:\newdb.mdf', 
MOVE 'newdb_log' TO 'c:\newdb_log.ldf'
```

if i run sql from sql profiler its works

how can u explain this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try killing all the users in the database your restoring to before running the restore, a restore will fail if there are any active connections to the db.  There is example code of how to do this [all over.](http://www.google.com/search?q=kill+all+users+database+sql+server)

Also make sure your connection string used when you call the restore from your application doesn't connect to the db your restoring to, but connects to something like master or msdb.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the connection you are using as a lock on the database so it can't restore.
When you run it directly, you haven't.

What about this?

```
con.execute("USE master" & vbcrlf &_
        "RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK='c:\old.bak' " & vbcrlf &_
        "RESTORE DATABASE newdb " & vbcrlf &_
        "FROM DISK='c:\old.bak' " & vbcrlf &_
        "WITH MOVE 'newdb' TO 'c:\newdb.mdf', " & vbcrlf &_
        "MOVE 'newdb_log' TO 'c:\newdb_log.ldf'")
```

Or changing the database in the connection string?

Answer (score 0):

To perform a restore you are blocked if the database is in use with other sessions.  Make sure you wait for a full 60 seconds and see if there are any timeout errors.

Comment: may i do 'wait time' with sql server, something like sleep, does it exists in sql server?

Comment: I don't know about sleeping in T-SQL, but you can set the IDbCommand.CommandTimeout property in .NET objects.  It is typically 30 seconds, while connection timeouts are defaulted to 60 seconds.

Comment: How long have you left it running?  Go get lunch or a coffee and come back some time later.  Also, try using SQL Profiler and the sp_who2 stored procedure to see if anything is blocking you.  Connection pools can make this tricky because even if you put it back in the pool, it's still connected.

Comment: As GBN above states, ensure that your asp application's connection string is for the MASTER database, not the one you're trying to restore...